# Better way to connect django model with django cms page/placeholder

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-cms

I'm making a website, and one of the features - News. I have a model News with some fields, to have a better user experience i thought that i need some more information for every News - html snippet and for good administrating that additional content for News, i decided that i need to use django csm.
So on every page i have an information from News model and in the end of that - html snippet made with cms.
And there is a problem - i don't know the better way to make my wishes.

Important bit: i want to make all connections with model slug.

1. I read docs about apphooks - but maybe it's not a good approach in my case? Couse apphooks make application embedding to django cms, but i need only the piece of creation and connecting of html template made by this cms.
2. Additionally i tried just take a Page made by cms and put it in my html, but it was something wrong there, maybe it is not possible? Maybe i can see pages only on cms urls?

`page = Page.objects.all()[0] # for example in views`

3. I tried to make the model placeholder, but again it was something wrong here, and i didn't see anything on default application page.
   `placeholders = PlaceholderRelationField()  @cached_property  def my_placeholder(self):      return get_placeholder_from_slot(self.placeholders, "slot_name")`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I fully understand the issue. My understanding of the question was: How can I add HTML content to a news item?

A simple solution to your problem might be to add a `HTMLField` to your news model. It comes from `djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields` and essentially allows to enter HTML rich text.

If that is the only use for django CMS, you might just take any rich text field with a suitable HTML editor for the django admin.

Comment: Thank you!
So, but i decided that i just need to use django-ckeditor with my model and it provides almost all needs to make the html content with tables/rich text/urls and etc.
As i understood django-cms connecting in your project - means that you will use cms like the main core of this project, because it requires all pages and urls dependent on cms. And if you just want to connect a rich html field in your model - ckeditor is better way.

Comment: Well, you can also add the cms to parts of your projects and manage urls yourself. But if you only need the rich text field, then django-ckeditor certainly is sufficient.